# Strange Simplified chinese message shows on EVERY browser on my Linux mint 18.02

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, linux-mint, virus

[image]

I don't know when and how the screen start to show on my EVERY browsers(firefox, chrome, chromnium..). When I input any words in the address line of browsers, the result will lead to the scree.

I had unistall and reboot and reinstall the firefox and chrome some many times recently, this message still exits....

I wonder how and why it shows on my EVERY browser of Linux mint 18.02. And please tell me how to remove or back to the original status. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because I use my T410i which is installed Linux mint 18.02 at home always, and that means I always connect with our community's wifi. Today, I took my T410i to my working space and using wifi there. Everything is fine!

It seems that the wifi route or server leads to the issue. However, I haven't talk with the administrator of our community's internet service. For now, we only can be sure that the issue is not triggered by Fcitx, Chrome, or Firefox.

If we find the final result, we will update the answer here:)